# Solving Future with android-Volley

Tags: android, android-volley, future

I'm a beginner with android.
I've got a project where i make GET request for an app on an API, i use volley for making my request and futur. My problem is that my futur is never solved and my app is blocked. 
First i know why my app is blocked, because i use get() method on the main thread but i need to do this because i need the result for making the next request so i need to wait the response. My problem is, i don't know why my request and my future are never solved.
 here the code from my main activity :

```
    private void populateSummoner(String region, String summonerName)throws JSONException {
    RequestFuture<JSONObject> summonerDataFutur;
    summonerDataFutur = requestData.requestSummonerData(region, summonerName);
    try {
        summoner = FactorySummoner.CreateSummoner(summonerDataFutur.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        Log.i(TAG,"Solving the summunerFuture timed Out "+ e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (InterruptedException e){
        Log.i(TAG,"Solving the summunerFuture was interrupt "+ e.getMessage());
    }catch (ExecutionException e){
        Log.i(TAG,"Solving the summunerFuture leads to an error "+ e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

I've created a class for manage my different request and it contains the request function

```
public class RequestData {

private static final String TAG = "RequestData";
private RequestQueue queue;

public RequestData(Context context){
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    queue.addRequestFinishedListener(new RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener<JsonObjectRequest>() {
        @Override
        public void onRequestFinished(Request<JsonObjectRequest> request) {
            Log.i(TAG,"fin d'une requete " + request.toString());
            try {
                Log.i(TAG, request.getBody().toString());
            } catch (AuthFailureError authFailureError) {
                authFailureError.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}


public RequestFuture<JSONObject> requestSummonerData(String region, String summonerName){
    Log.i(TAG,"Begin RequestData for summoner : "+summonerName+" on region : "+region);
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(Utils.HTTPS);
    builder.append(getRegionUrl(region));
    builder.append(Utils.REQUEST_SUMMONER);
    builder.append(summonerName);
    builder.append(Utils.API_KEY);
    Log.i(TAG, "url built : "+builder.toString());

    RequestFuture<JSONObject> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(builder.toString(),null,future,future);

    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
    return future;
}

private String getRegionUrl(String region){
    String url="";
    if (Utils.HOST_ADDRESS.containsKey(region)){
        url = Utils.HOST_ADDRESS.get(region);
    }
    else{
        //todo implement exception
        Log.i(TAG, "no host address for this region");
    }
    Log.i(TAG,"Server address : "+url);
    return url;
}
```

}

As you can see i've tried to implement the onRequestFinished() on my queue to see if the request is done and it seems not.
I've already search on the internet but never find a good solution and the volley documentation is not very helpfull -_-
Help me please !

Answer (score 0):

> I'm a beginner with android.

Welcome!

> My problem is that my futur is never solved and my app is blocked.

What does "is never solved" mean?

> First i know why my app is blocked, because i use get() method on the main thread but i need to do this because i need the result for making the next request so i need to wait the response.

You don't *need* to do this. You can make your first request while you show a spinner or other UI for indicating progress, then kick off the next request when the first completes.

> My problem is, i don't know why my request and my future are never solved. here the code from my main activity :

Again, what does "solved" mean? Have you [debugged your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html) to see what errors or exceptions are being thrown?

Comment: By never solved i mean i can rever reach  the result of the futur.

Comment: After yes it would be better for the user to indicate a work is in progress i will doing it after solve the future problem ;)
And the real problem is i don't have any error, if i don't set the timeout on the get() the app will froze forever and with the timeout the e.getMessage() only said null.

Comment: If your request just hangs, then you more than likely have a server problem. If you own the server, debug that end and make sure it's actually receiving the request and returning a response. If you don't contact the owner of the server with your issue. Good luck.